# java reflection getFields for private member| accessing object name value dynamically

Tags: java, reflection

I want to print all of the class's properties with their name and values.  I have used reflection, but `getFields` give me length of 0.

```
RateCode getMaxRateCode = instance.getID(Integer.parseInt((HibernateUtil
            .currentSession().createSQLQuery("select max(id) from ratecodes")
            .list().get(0).toString())));
for (Field f : getMaxRateCode.getClass().getFields()) {
            try {
                System.out.println(f.getGenericType() + " " + f.getName() + " = "
                        + f.get(getMaxRateCode));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

RateCode.java

```
    private Integer rateCodeId;
    private String code;       
    private BigDecimal childStay;       
    private DateTime bookingTo;
    private Short minPerson;      
    private Boolean isFreeNightCumulative = false;
    private boolean flat = false;
    private Timestamp modifyTime;
```

Comment: What does your `RateCode` look like?

Comment: there you go. None of your fields is `public`. See @Peter's answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Class.getFields() only gives you public fields.  Perhaps you wanted the JavaBean getters?

```
BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(getMaxRateCode.getClass());
for ( PropertyDescriptor pd : info.getPropertyDescriptors() )
    System.out.println(pd.getName()+": "+pd.getReadMethod().invoke(getMaxRateCode));
```

---

If you want to access the private fields, you can use getDeclaredFields() and call field.setAccessible(true) before you use them.

```
for (Field f : getMaxRateCode.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Object o;
    try {
        o = f.get(getMaxRateCode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        o = e;
    }
    System.out.println(f.getGenericType() + " " + f.getName() + " = " + o);
}
```

Comment: Using properties will give access to any public getters. If you want to view the underlying fields the best way would be to use your IDE's debugger and place a breakpoint where you have the result.

Comment: u r right with IDE but i want to print this and i have getter/setter as u all ready said. thanx for example.

Answer (score 15):

`getFields` only returns public fields.  If you want all fields, see [getDeclaredFields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29)

Comment: All answers should look like this. :D